# How a Window service using OWIN can go through firewall?

Tags: c#, windows, tcp, owin, firewall

I have a C# Windows service acting as a Web Proxy, using OWIN. I need this service to be able to go through the Windows firewall.
I added my service in the authorized applications, but when my firewall is enabled, I cannot connect (from the outside) to the TCP port my service has opened : I receive a SYN message, but my service doesn't answer to enable the connection.
However, using TCPView, I saw the port opened by my proxy is controlled by "System", which I cannot authorize through firewall ...

P.S : I cannot open ports, for security reasons, I am trying to find an alternative to it.

Thanks !

Comment: What's your setting of your applicatin rule?

Comment: Usually you use port forwarding on an allowable port number.  Where is the proxy located?  The proxy should be able to forward the message.

Comment: @aDisplayName I don't get what you are asking, sorry :d

Comment: @jdweng The proxy is on a windows computer, and I would like to avoid adding rule of specific port.

Comment: Inside or Outside firewall?  If you cannot open ports can you make a HTTP connection?  You may need to send the TCP over HTTP.